# juniper vlan-ccc vs ethernet-ccc for eompls

Tags: vlan, ethernet, juniper, mpls

In juniper `ethernet-ccc` transports customer's vlan end to end.  Does `vlan-ccc` also transport customer's vlan across as well?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question directly, yes the original VLAN tag will be preserved.  However, don't look at it from the perspective of preserving VLAN tags, look at it as preserving the entire layer-2 header (except for maybe the address).

- `ethernet-ccc` simply assumes that each end of the cross-connect has similar ethernet features.  Ethernet can send tagged or untagged frames, etc.
- `vlan-ccc` assumes that each end of the cross-connect will send tagged frames using VLAN 512 or higher using TPID  0x8100.
- `extended-vlan-ccc` assumes the same as `vlan-ccc`, but can use all VLAN IDs and all TPID values.

All of that said, if you have pseudowires, VPLS, or other features that are pushing/popping/swapping VLANs, you have to account for that on your other customer facing interfaces.

I'm happy to edit my answer if you need further clarification.